# Forms on Tabs updating other Tabs

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access application that is basically one big tabbed interface, Sometimes information is updated on one tab that may affect other tabs. I'd like an event to requery certain tabs when they are selected. I've tried the on-click event for the tab and on focus for the form, but it is not doing it for me.

I'm using Access 2007 but I'm in Access 2000 compatibility mode (Is this a problem)

Which event should I be using to update the tabs? Some are display only.

TIA

Comment: More information is needed about the kinds of controls on the other tabs. The default behavior in Access is that controls that are bound to the same fields will update automatically without you needing to do anything, so there must be something else going on here that you've omitted from your description of the problem.

Comment: Hi David. I've got reference table updates on some tabs, when they are updated the comboboxes on the transaction tabs don't update without a requery or an F5. I also have a linked hierarchy of Customer->Job->Item for transactions with item sub-types. I've been thinking of moving my customer to the Access 2007 run-time as I thought the compatibility mode could be causing problems.

Comment: For combo boxes, the key is that any control that updates data that's displayed in a combo box should have an AfterUpdate event that requeries the combo box. You can write a sub to requery and call that from all the relevant AfterUpdate events (or make it a function and just assign it as the AfterUpdate property, `=RequeryComboBox()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be working. Switching to 2007 shouldn't affect how that works.

Are you doing the requery on the whole form, or on the individual combo boxes. e.g.,

```
Private Sub Combo10_GotFocus()
    me.Combo10.Requery
End Sub
```

You could also do something like putting a GotFocus on one of the fields in each tab (I can't remember, but I thought there was a default field that got focus whenever a tab is displayed).

Comment: Thanks @CodeSlave, I have been doing this but looking for a better answer. The switching to 2007 thing was about new events becoming available for 2007, I don't know where to look that up.

Comment: Well @CodeSlave, I've considered the options, including @David-W-Fentons idea of a requery function after update. My conclusion is that requery on focus is the most effective, but I have also taught the user to use F5 to refresh if there are any scenarios that I haven't covered.